# Git Interactive Rebase Shows commits from master branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I am trying to squash a few commits from my branch before merging a pull request.

When doing `git log` I can scroll down to the commits I want to squash (14 commits back).

Doing `git rebase -i HEAD~14` shows my comments and also commits made onto master, moving back the commits I want to squash

Comment: Are you sure that you are `checkout branch` before `git rebase --interactive`?

Comment: Yes I did, my branch was "up to date"

Comment: Did you checkout your actual branch that you want to rebase from master? It looks like normal situation when you checkout you have access to previous history snapshots from master.

Comment: What do you mean by "actual branch". I did `git checkout <branch I want to rebase>`

Comment: And then you made some commits and want to squash few of them and push and merge to master, is that right?

Comment: I want to push to my branch, if everything is fine upon review it will be merged into master

Comment: Then squash commits in your branch and merge them to master. I wouldn't recommend you to squash commits before checkout from master.

Answer (score 0):

In short that is normal situation that you see previous history commits because you checkout from master.